# Between genres, which type of movies seems to be more rated by age group?

Tags: sql, group-by, hive, case

how can i join three tables, find the most rated genre from genres and group them in age.

i have already created the tables

i did something like this, but i know is wrong

```
SELECT count(CASE WHEN (genre and age < 40 ) THEN rating ELSE null END),
count(CASE WHEN (genre age < 40 )  THEN rating ELSE null END)
FROM user
INNER JOIN data ON data.userid = user.userid
RIGHT JOIN item ON item.movieid = data.itemid
```

Comment: Can you please post some sample data and expected result?

Comment: data are from here: https://grouplens.org/datasets/movielens/ , ml-100k.zip , the file text are inside, data, genre, user, item. expected results: i want the output to be like under 40 the most high rated genre is HORROR @AnkitBajpai

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you question correctly, I don't think you need a CASE statement.

```
SELECT age, genre, count(rating) total_rating
from User u
inner join Data d on u.userId = d.userId 
inner join Item i on i.itemId = d.itemId
WHERE age >= 40
Group by age, genre;
```

I did also try to use a case statement, but it's a bit more ugly.

```
SELECT age, 
       genre, 
       sum (CASE WHEN age>=40 
            then 1 
            ELSE 0 
            end)  as 'UNDER40'
       
from User u
inner join Data d on u.userId = d.userId 
inner join Item i on i.itemId = d.itemId
where age >=40
Group by age, genre
```

[db fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/joLT6HnNRw7TtV7WyjQw8w/0)

Comment: thanks for the answer, i believe the problem here is that i cant join the table item with the data, beacause there is no itemid column in item table @Jocohan